# Asymptotics for this limit iteration with $f(x)= 2x + x^5 ,g(x) = x + x^3$

Tags: limits, asymptotics, dynamical-systems, closed-form, supremum-and-infimum

Consider $x>0$

Let

$$f(x)= 2x + x^5$$

$$g(x) = x + x^3$$

$$f(r(x))=r(f(x))=id(x)$$

$$g(u(x)) = u(g(x))=id(x)$$

Where $id(x)$ is the identity function mapping all values to itself.

Let $*^{[y]}$ denote the $y$ th iteration of $*$.

Now consider for $x>0$ :

$$ h(x) = \lim_{n \to +\infty} f^{[n]}( g(r^{[n]}(x)) ) $$

$$m(x) = max[ f^{[1]}( g(r^{[1]}(x)) ), f^{[2]}( g(r^{[2]}(x)) ), f^{[3]}( g(r^{[3]}(x)) ) , ...]$$

How are $h(x)$ and $m(x)$ related ? Are they equal for all $x>0$ ?

What are good closed forms or good closed form asymptotics for $h(x)$ and $m(x)$ when $x>0$ ?

Comment: @insipidintegrator why is what you wrote true? I'm not following.

Comment: @insipidintegrator Note that $g(r(x))\neq id(x)$.  $\quad$ One way that these could be related, is if the sequences are increasing, then $h(x) = m(x)$.